# Textures only work on vertical surfaces

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, unreal-5

I'm trying to apply a megascan texture (hardwood) to a floor but it only looks right on vertical surfaces. If I apply it to a cube and rotate the cube, the texture turns weird on the horizontal faces and looks good on the upright ones. I used worldAlignedTexture object as indicated by this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUW3HHMhx1A&t=171s

This is the blueprint for the texture
[image]

What gives?

Comment: Can you show us your material graph setup?

Comment: @DMGregory added pic with the texture blueprint

Comment: I notice you've connected the XY texture pins on the top two boxes, instead of the XYZ pin as shown in the tutorial. Any particular reason for that?

Comment: @DMGregory there's no particular reason, but it also doesn't affect the outcome. Same thing happens if you use the XYZ output

Comment: that was it, actually. The first one at  the top. I changed from xy to xyz and it worked on all sides. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first alignedWorldTexture object the top. I changed from xy to xyz and it worked on all sides.